# Writing text to gzip file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, gzip

Following tutorials and examples found in blogs and in other threads here, it appears that the way to write to a `.gz` file is to open it in binary mode and write the string as is:

```
import gzip
with gzip.open('file.gz', 'wb') as f:
    f.write('Hello world!')
```

I tried it, and got the following exception:

```
  File "C:\Users\Tal\Anaconda3\lib\gzip.py", line 258, in write
    data = memoryview(data)
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

So I tried opening the file in text mode:

```
import gzip
with gzip.open('file.gz', 'w') as f:
    f.write('Hello world!')
```

But I got the same error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Tal\Anaconda3\lib\gzip.py", line 258, in write
    data = memoryview(data)
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

How can this problem be addressed in Python3?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

#### `mode='wb'`

When writing to a file opened in binary mode, you must write bytes, not string. Encode your string using `str.encode`:

```
with gzip.open('file.gz', 'wb') as f:
    f.write('Hello world!'.encode())
```

---

#### `mode='wt'`

(found by OP) Alternatively, you can write strings to your file when you open it in the `wt` (explicit *text*) mode:

```
with gzip.open('file.gz', 'wt') as f:
    f.write('Hello world!')
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#examples-of-usage) has a couple of handy examples on usage.

Comment: Instead of `'Hello world!'.encode()` simply write `b'Hello world!'`

Comment: @Sven the example is to demonstrate how you would write strings via a variable -- you'd have to call string.encode() then. I assumed it would be easier to explain like this.